# Using class algebra, if the intersection of classes A and B is the empty class, then how do you prove the difference of A and B is A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For reference, I'm self-studying Charles C. Pinter A Book of Set Theory. The exercise in 1.3 6b. calls for using only class algebra which is all the theorems used in that particular chapter. I have proof which starts out with the intersection of A and the complement of B being a subclass of A, and then deriving the subclass in the other direction. However, using just class algebra, I haven't been able to come up with a proof. I have tried working by starting with A-B, then to A intersect complement B, but using purely class algebra, I haven't been able to crack it. I've worked on this problem for awhile and looked at by using various theorems and the examples such as the one nearing the end of the chapter with this exercise. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. [image: A proof without the use of class algebra]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
A - B
&= A \cap B' && \text{by definition}\\
&= \emptyset \cup (A \cap B') && \text{by an identity law}\\
&= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B') && \text{by hypothesis}\\
&= A \cap (B \cup B') && \text{by a distributive law}\\
&= A \cap \mathcal{U} && \text{by Pinter Thm 1.26(vii)}\\
&= A && \text{by an identity law}.
\end{align*}